# When running Asp.NET Core App the app fails to launch with a 502.5 Process error on local IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I'm having an issue when running my project. This project was running just fine previously. Something has happened to cause the following error to appear in the stdout log.

> Error:   An assembly specified in the application dependencies
>   manifest (.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'AutoMapper', version: '6.2.2'
>       path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/AutoMapper.dll'

Things I have tried:

1. Clear the nuget cache
2. Restore nuget cache
3. Restarted Visual Studio 2017
4. Restarted IIS
5. Gave Full Access to the 'Everyone' role to the
   folder where the files are located

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** This is the output from the Output Pane

[image: This is the output from the Output Pane]

Comment: How are you publishing to IIS?

Comment: try delete the bin and obj folders and then rebuild solution

Comment: @CalC - I'm running the project from Visual Studio, I'm not publishing to IIS myself.

Comment: The only thing that will cause that in development is something failing in the application startup. That means you have an error either in `Program.cs`, `StartUp.cs` or some middleware being utilized by your application. The latter would likely only be an issue with custom middleware, since all the ASP.NET Core stuff is thoroughly tested.

Comment: In Visual Studio, select "ASP.NET Core Web Server" from the dropdown on the Output pane. That will show you the output of from the Core app, which will likely include some exception in the log. Fix the exception.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thank you for the response. I have taken a look at what you mentioned. I updated my question to include a screenshot of the Output Pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending sometime on this, none of the fixes suggested worked. After spending a lot of time looking up what the potential issue is, I decided to check for any available visual studio updates.

After I updated Visual Studio 2017 everything worked.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, add the following to your .csproj file and publish again.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had tried this previously and I still get the same error.